# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, amazon-ses

In env file mentioned

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
MAIL_PASSWORD="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=

SES_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
SES_SECRET="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
SES_Region="US East (N. Virginia)"
```

Unable to send email in laravel by amazon ses ,all the credentials are correct but i keep on getting this error
The user credentials are correct but I still receive the following error:

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
>   "email@example.com" using 2 possible authenticators

Comment: You found any solution for this issue ?

Comment: issue is with the region location